# BoxWhiskerChart - Displaying Frameticks Bottom and Top

Tags: plotting

Is there an easy way to display Automatically the Frameticks at the bottom and top in a BoxWhiskerChart? Currently it is only showing the numbers at the bottom.

```
data = Table[{i, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[i, 2], 100]}, {i, 
100, 125}];
BoxWhiskerChart[data[[All, 2]], BarOrigin -> Left, 
ChartLabels -> data[[All, 1]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, 
FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try All instead of Automatic in the FrameTicks option

```
data = Table[{i, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[i, 2], 100]}, {i, 
    100, 125}];
BoxWhiskerChart[data[[All, 2]], BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> data[[All, 1]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {All, All}}]
```

[image: Plot]

I can't figure out why it doesn't respect the None on the left/right edges, anyone knows?

Comment: In Mma 8.0 the "None" is respected

Comment: @belisarius I run 8.0.4.0 on linux, which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mma 8.0.0.0 That's the difference

Comment: I'm using 8.0.4 MacOSX

Comment: @DiegoZviovich MacOSX? Qué es eso? :D